# Getting Imports/Exports from an PE using a Ghidra Script

Tags: reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm using ghidra to Reverse Engineer an EXE file. I want to extract the imports and exports from the symbol tree. 
I've Written this script but it doesn't return anything.

```
sm = currentProgram.getSymbolTable()
symb = sm.getSymbolIterator("Imports")
for s in symb:
     print(s)
```

but when i use this script to get all the functions from the symbol tree, it works

```
symb = sm.getSymbolIterator()
for s in symb:
     print(s)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does solves your issue?

```
sm = currentProgram.getSymbolTable()
symb = sm.getExternalSymbols()
for s in symb:
     print(s)
```

Comment: Yes it does!.
Thank you so much.